# What's the difference between Windows and Linux/OS X when using the Java SSLSocket?

Tags: java, linux, macos, sockets, ssl

I wrote a multi-server chat system based on Java under Windows. At the security part, I created one keystore to create the SSLSocket. When I launch 3 servers, it works on Windows(Win10 14393.321) but fails on OS X(Version 10.12 (16A323)) and Linux(Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS). It really confused me. Here is the keystore part:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",keyFilepath);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",keyFilepath);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","password");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");
```

And when I run the third server on OS X or Linux, it shows:

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>
> at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668) at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.(SSLSocketImpl.java:427) at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88)
>   at server.AuthorizeServer.MessageReceive(AuthorizeServer.java:99) at
>   server.AuthorizeServer.main(AuthorizeServer.java:64) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)

This is my first time asking on StackOverflow and I really looking forward to your kind help.
Thanks!

Comment: I think it would be good to say in your question the version of Windows, OS X and Linux that you have tested, where it succeed and where it fails.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I have added that.

Comment: The difference is that the failing case is failing to connect at the TCP level, because the IP:port is wrong or there is nothing listening at it. Neither your keystore nor your truststore nor `SSLSocket` nor JSSE nor Java has anything to do with it.

Comment: @EJP You are right. It was the port problem. I set the server ports to 80 and used 'sudo' before the commands and it worked. But still a little confused me that why the other ports like '5544' doesn't work (but work on Windows)?

Comment: Impossible to comment without actually knowing what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Connection refused is an error message from the TCP stack and means that it could not connect with TCP to the other side. Since SSL/TLS is a layer on top of TCP and is only started once the TCP connect succeeded it means that the problem is not caused by different behavior at the SSL/TLS layer.

That this is not cause by the SSL layer but the TCP layer can also be seen by the stacktrace: *Connection refused at java.net.**PlainSocket**Impl.socketConnect*

More likely is that there is something blocking the TCP connection (firewall) or that you've tried to listen/connect to the wrong IP address (e.g. trying to reach a server listening on 127.0.0.1 on Windows from the Linux system). But is impossible to say from the currently provided information what exactly is the case.

Comment: Actually, if I change the SSLSocket to normal Socket, the system works well.

Comment: @CrazyEric: that's really strange since according to the stacktrace the problem is caused by a plain socket connect: *Connection refused  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect*, i.e. before any SSL/TLS stuff is done. I think you need to provide [a minimal, complete and verifieable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that one can see what you are actually doing.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the server ports to '80' and add 'sudo' and the problem solved.